# How to pass Authorization Header while executing logic app workflow without enabling Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to pass the authorization header(Bearer Token) while calling the logic app without enabling Azure Active Directory? I have my own Azure B2C Token and want to send in headers and this will be useful to utilise further HTTP requests in side workflow

Comment: Have you tried using HTTP action. 

[HTTP Connection](https://i.imgur.com/lzZsaBq.png)

Comment: I want to pass the Authorization token when HTTP Request is Received so that I can give the same token to further HTTP Connectors.

Comment: Can you please add what is the response from the request.

Comment: I am passing the authorization header while executing Logic App and it is throwing this error -

{

    "error": {

        "code": "OAuthAccessPolicyNotFound",

        "message": "'Authorization' header is not allowed, The OAuth authentication policy is not enabled for the workflow."

    }

}

Comment: Noted!! but I meant to say what is the response for your trigger. Are you receiving any Bearer Token from the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a HTTP trigger (When a HTTP request is received) in your logic app, the request headers can be found in the Dynamic content list:

[image]

You should be able to catch a token in a header like this:

```
triggerOutputs()['headers']?['token']
```